# Initialize application context during testing excluding the spring integration beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-messaging

I am working on Spring Boot application which uses Spring Integration and Mqtt support. Here we have a test to check if the application context is started properly.

```
class ApplicationTests {

  private @Autowired transient ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Test
  void mainMethodTest() {
    Application.main(new String[] {});
    Assertions.assertNotNull(this.applicationContext);
  }
}
```

but this test will if the Mqtt Broker is not running.

```
@Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mqtt")
  public MqttConnectionOptions mqttConnectOptions() {
    return new MqttConnectionOptions();
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn("mqttConnectOptions")
  public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
    Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler mqttv5PahoMessageHandler =
        new Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler(mqttConnectOptions(), QueueConfigs.CLIENT_ID);
    mqttv5PahoMessageHandler.setAsync(true);
    return mqttv5PahoMessageHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow simulatorReadingsOutFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.handle(mqttOutbound());
  }
```

tests will **fail** because the above **beans** will not be created during the **testing** without an **mqtt broker** running in the environment. is there a way to **skip** the integration flow related beans or mock them during the testing of **ApplicationContext**.

Comment: Have you tried making `@MockBean` instances inside `ApplicationTests`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution as @ferrouskid said in the comment is to use `@MockBean` in your `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@MockBean
IntegrationFlow simulatorReadingsOutFlow;
```

Another solution is to use a `@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "mqttOutboundEndpoint")` on the class method. But it is going to work only if really use Spring Testing Framework, including or not Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context.

However if you do that yourself like that `Application.main(new String[] {});`, you don't rely on the Spring Testing environment and you just run the whole application outside of the testing scope. Consider to learn more how to test Spring Boot projects: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing